# Can you make Sudo display a message when access is granted?

Tags: sudo

Sudo already tells the user when access is denied:

```
[jayman@this-machine:~]$ sudo echo hi
[sudo] password for jayman: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jayman: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jayman: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

```
[git@this-machine:~]$ sudo echo hi
Sorry, user git may not run sudo on this-machine.
```

Sudo doesn’t, however, tell the user when access has been granted. Consider what happens when `sudo dd if=foo of=bar` gets run. For me, one of two things happens:

1. Sudo prompts me for a password. I enter the password and see the terminal go to the next line, but `dd` doesn’t output anything for a while. I end up waiting a few seconds to make sure that Sudo isn’t waiting to say “Sorry, try again” and prompt me for the password again.
2. Sudo doesn’t prompt me for a password because my credentials are cached. `dd` doesn’t output anything for a while. I end up waiting a few seconds to make sure that Sudo isn’t just taking a while to prompt me for a password.

If Sudo printed a message after my password was accepted, then I wouldn’t have to wait to figure out whether or not `dd` had started yet. Is there any way to get Sudo to print a message when access has been granted?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a Bash script named `sudo`:

```bash
set -e
console="$(tty)"
readonly console

/path/to/real/sudo -v
# Sudo normally writes directly to the terminal device instead of
# writing to stdout, so that’s what I’m doing here
echo Access granted. &> "$console"
/path/to/real/sudo "$@"
```

Then, I set my `PATH` to `"/path/to/fake/sudo/dir:$PATH"`. There are a few limitations to this solution:

- It won’t work properly if credential caching is disabled.
- If your credentials aren’t cached, then `sudo --help` or `sudo -k` will prompt for a password.

Comment: You can avoid prompting all the time by asking `sudo` to run an innocuous command instead; `/path/to/real/sudo echo Access granted. &> "$console"`.

Comment: Hm… I would rather not run a command with Sudo unless I have to, but that change would make the script shorter. Also, I should clarify the part that says “It will always prompt you for your password”. In reality, it will prompt for a password if there aren’t cached credentials already.